# How can I update the old Twitter logo on Mosaico to the new X icon?

Tags: mosaico

I need to update the Twitter logo on the socials block on Mosaico, but I can't see where to edit this to the new X logo instead? Any advice?

Comment: I recommend you call Elon and tell him to change it back. The old logo was better!

Answer (score 3):

I put in [an issue for the mosaico people](https://github.com/voidlabs/versafix-social-icons/issues/12) to update their logos. However, they are not very friendly or responsive.

Temporarily you can replace the icons in the folder, just keep the same file name - assuming you are using latest mosaico, go here:
/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/templates/versafix-1/img/icons and keep it 96px

- tw-black-96.png
- tw-bw-96.png
- tw-bwb-96.png
- tw-colors-96.png
- tw-coloured-96.png
- tw-rdbl-96.png
- tw-rdcol-96.png
- tw-rdw-96.png
- tw-sqbw-96.png
- tw-sqbwb-96.png
- tw-sqcolors-96.png
- tw-sqrdbl-96.png
- tw-sqrdcol-96.png
- tw-sqrdw-96.png
- tw-white-96.png

If a dev in the civi community could run the script for us, that would be ideal. Then we could have a common icon set for patching.

Note: As jon indicated, you would have to repatch with every mosaico update.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it will be overwritten on Mosaico upgrade.  So you either need to a) re-apply after each update or b) you can go to **Administer » CiviMail » Mosaico Settings**, set a custom template directory, and copy your versafix-1 template into the custom template directory.